# How to get the title to the next line in a card?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I an working on Card from antd. I want to get the rest of title to the next line if it is long. For eg, title is displayed as "This title needs to go to ne..." but I want it to be displayed in two lines. "This title needs to go to" in the first line and "next line" in the next line. I know we can make use of inline size to get to the next line but I don't want to make use of pixel as width since I want to make it interactive. This is the code I have written :

```
<Row gutter={24}>
  <Col xs={24} md={10}>
    <Card
      title={<span>This title name should go to next line if instead of displaying ...</span>}
      bodyStyle={{ paddingTop: 5 }}
    >
      <p>Card description</p>
    </Card>
 </Col>
</Row>
```

How do I get it to the next line using inline size and make it interactive?

Comment: Try adding this CSS

  [display: flex;  
  flex-wrap: wrap; ] 

This will wrap the text to the next line

Comment: @Vinoth.R I tried this but instead of going to the next line, the title goes out of the card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use break in your span tag.

```
 <Card
      title={<span> first line <br/> second line</span>}
      bodyStyle={{ paddingTop: 5 }}
    />
```

or target card header using css

```
.ant-card-head-title {
  text-overflow: unset !important;
  white-space: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: The title length will keep on changing so, I can't use break

Comment: I had not thought of using whitespace. Thank you